# swapping of objects in c++ based on specific data in those objects?

Tags: c++, class

this is a store management system.
in which item's name,price and quantity is to be entered by the user and it should give a sorted output based on the price of item from low to high.
i have implemented the sorting method used in integers..but with objects...
what am i doing wrong here?
p.s: i'm a beginner and new at stackoverflow

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class item{
        public:
            string name;
            int price;
            int quan;

            string getname(){
                cin>>name;;
                return name;}
            int getprice(){
                cin>>price;
                return price;}
            int getquan(){
                cin>>quan;
                return quan;
                }
            void display(){
                cout<<"\nname of item: "<<name;
                cout<<"\nprice: "<<price;
                cout<<"\nquantity: "<<quan;
                }
            void copie(item b ,item c){

                b.name=c.name;
                b.price=c.price;
                b.quan=c.quan;
                }
};

int main(){
    int n;
    cout<<"Enter number of items: ";
    cin>>n;
    item a[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<"\nenter name ";
        a[i].getname();
        cout<<"enter price ";
        a[i].getprice();
        cout<<"enter quantity ";
        a[i].getquan();

    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i].display();

    }
//swapping begins
     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){//cout<<"in loop 1";
        for(int j=0;j<n-1;j++){//cout<<"in loop 2";
                item temp,temp1;
                //cout<<"temp,temp1 initalized";
                int x,y;
                x=a[j].price;
                y=a[j+1].price;
                //cout<<"\nname "<<a[j].name<<"\nx= "<<x<<"\nname "<<a[j+1].name<<"\n"<<"y= "<<y;
            if(x>y){//cout<<"comapriosn";
               //is swapping happening here?
               temp.copie(temp1,a[j]);
               cout<<"\n"<<temp1.price;
               temp.copie(a[j],a[j+1]);
               temp.copie(a[j+1],temp1);
               //cout<<"\nname "<<a[j].name<<"\nprice "<<a[j].price;

            }
        }
    }

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        a[i].display();
        }
        //somecode


return 0;}
```

Comment: Why are you tagging your question a Java question? What does this have to do with Java programming? Tag removed.

Comment: Same for the [tag:c] tag, as it's a different language from C++. You're new here, so please understand that the two most important components of your question are your question title and tags, and you want to make sure that you get both right. Please go through the how-to-ask sections of the [help] to see how to best use this site.

Comment: `item a[n];` is not standard C++ unless `n` is a constant expression.

Comment: `temp1 = a[j]` should do the job of `temp.copie(temp1, a[j])`. `std::swap(a[j], a[j+1]);` would do the job of your 3 `copie`. and `std::sort(a, a + n, [](const Item& lhs, const Item& rhs) { return lhs.price < rhs.price; });` would do the job of your bubble sort.

Comment: `getX` is a bad name for setting X from user input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`copie` function is not working as expected because `b` and `c` are local variable in that function so modification not affects. Instead of catching with with `normal` variable catch with **reference** variable.

Modify `copie` function as

```
void copie(item &b ,item &c){ /** catch with reference variable */

                        b.name=c.name;
                        b.price=c.price;
                        b.quan=c.quan;
                }
```

by catching with **reference variable**  you can **save the memory** because for `b( in item &b)`  there is `no separate memory` is created, it will use the `same memory` which was allocated for `a[j] (while calling  temp.copie(a[j],a[j+1]);)`.

*i have implemented the sorting method used in integers..but with objects* => you use can **template** for the same logic to work for any input/data type.

I hope it  helps.

Comment: Btw, `copie` should be `item& operator = (const Item& rhs) = default;`.

Comment: yes @Jarod42 if need to overload `=` but here by `default assignment operator` will do the work. Am I right ?

Comment: Default is correct. that's why I put ` = default;` ;-) (available since C++11)

Comment: Thanks @Jarod42 for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
       temp.copie(temp1,a[j]);
       cout<<"\n"<<temp1.price;
       temp.copie(a[j],a[j+1]);
       temp.copie(a[j+1],temp1);
```

with

```
       cout << endl << a[j].price;
       swap(a[j], a[j + 1]);
```

(You may have to

```
#include <utility>
```

to get `swap()` to work.)

Comment: One step further, and you can suggest `std::sort`.